# PHP / Regex: extract string from string

Tags: php, regex, str-replace, substr, strstr

I just started using PHP and hope someone here can help me with this.

I am trying to extract a string ("`myRegion`") from another string ("`mainString`") where my string always starts with "`myCountry:` " and ends with a semicolon (`;`) if the main string contains more countries after myCountry OR without anything if the main string does not contain more countries after it.

**Examples to show different options for main string:**

- myCountry: **region1, region2**
- myCountry: **region1, region2, region3**; otherCountry: region1
- otherCountry: region1; myCountry: **region1**; otherCountry: region1, region2

What I want to extract is always the part in bold.

**I was thinking of something like the following but this doesn't look right yet:**

```
$myRegions = strstr($mainString, $myCountry);                   
$myRegions = str_replace($myCountry . ": ", "", $myRegions);
$myRegions = substr($myRegions, 0, strpos($myRegions, ";"));
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this, Mike.

Comment: FYI: You are not using regular expressions in your example. `str_replace` does not use REGEX - `preg_replace` does http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: I know, just wanted to mention in case it is a better alternative here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using regular expression:

```
preg_match('/myCountry\:\s*([^\;]+)/', $mainString, $out);
$myRegion = $out[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! One question: if there would be more countries after myCountry will this just go until the first semicolon after myCountry (which is what I need) ?

Comment: Yeah. It just takes everything from `myCountry:` to the first `;`

Comment: Awesome - thanks a lot. Confirmed it works great and is even faster than expected.

Answer (score 5):

Since from the comments it seems like you are interested in non-regex solutions and since you are a beginner and interested in learning, here's another possible approach using [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).
(*Hope this is not uncalled for*).

Firstly, recognise that you have definitions seperated by `;` since it is:

`myCountry: region1, region2, region3` **`;`**  `otherCountry: region1`

So, using [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), you can generate an array of your definitions:

```
$string = 'otherCountry: region1; myCountry: region1; otherCountry: region2, region3';
$definitions = explode (';', $string);
```

giving you

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(21) "otherCountry: region1"
  [1]=>
  string(19) " myCountry: region1"
  [2]=>
  string(31) " otherCountry: region2, region3"
}
```

You could now iterate over this array (using [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)) and explode it using `:` and then explode the second result of that using `,`.
This way you could build up an associative array holding your Countries with their respective regions.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($definitions as $countryDefinition) {
  $parts = explode (':', $countryDefinition); // parting at the :
  $country = trim($parts[0]); // look up trim to understand this
  $regions = explode(',', $parts[1]); // exploding by the , to get the regions array
  if(!array_key_exists($country, $result)) { // check if the country is already defined in $result
    $result[$country] = array();
  }
  $result[$country] = array_merge($result[$country], $regions);
}
```

Just a very [simple example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5658d199843d9460caa75a2133b80a22c181720e) to play with.

Comment: I got 502 error on simple example's link, it is dead ?

Comment: @Sunchock eval.in seems to be down/closed. I added a new link to the same code on another plattform. For future reference: You can also just copy the first code block and the last code block and try it yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I suggested an eddit for your array example because it's a little bit confusing.
The array had 3 entries but you write only 2 entries. They match with your first sentence but not with your code part with explode.

Comment: @Sunchock I didn't see your edit but i think i fixed it?

Comment: I didn't see changes
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) " myCountry: region1, region2, region3"
  [1]=>
  string(31) " otherCountry: region1"
}
would become
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "otherCountry: region1"
  [1]=>
  string(31) " myCountry: region1"
  [2]=>
  string(31) " otherCountry: region2, region3"
}

Because your array match with your first sentence but not with your example using explode